# Can I re-use my LEGO Store Pick a Brick cup?

Tags: shopping, pick-a-brick, lego-store

I was wondering if anyone went into a LEGO store with their old Pick a Brick cup and got a discount for re-using it, or do you have to buy a new cup?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can. Or at least I've been able to reuse mine in the past. I believe it was $0.50 off for the big cup and $0.25 for the small cup.

Comment: Indeed. They used to slap a sticker on the cup reminding you of that fact, but they quit doing that a few month ago.

Comment: I think it's 75p in UK stores for a large cup.

Comment: In 2017, the discount is 75 cent for a large cup and 50 cent for a small one. Initial prices are 17,99 Euro and 9,99 Euro, respectively.

Comment: Still 0,75€ for a large cup in 2022.